# Translate site using session in php

Tags: php, locale, session-cookies, translate

I try to translate my site using PHP and make it to remind the language even if the user navigate between pages and I can't do it in the way I want. The way I want is using a 'locale' folder.

The main file is called index.php that can contain something like this:

```
<?php
include "locale/en.php";
echo $locale['test'];
?>
```

..and the en.php is in "locale" folder near "it.php", "ro.php", "fr.php" and so on. En.php file contains:

```
<?php
$locale['test'] = "anything";
?>
```

Now here's the problem.. I know the term "session" in php, but I don't know how to make this syntax work in PHP.

```
session_start();
if user clicks the Italy flag{
translate the site in italian;
}else{ 
if the user click the France flag{
translate the site in french
}else{...
```

I wish when the user navigate between pages to see the content in language that he selected. Optionally to store the language that he selected in a cookie to see the site in language that he wants even if comes back to site second, third... time. Thanks, and sorry for my bad language :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it is:

```
session_start(); //include this at the top of your page(s)

if(!isset($_SESSION['language'])){
    $_SESSION['language'] = 'en'; // set the default language
    }

if(isset($_GET['setLanguage'])){
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['setLanguage']; //if the user change language
    }

$allowedLanguages = array('en','es');  

if(in_array($_SESSION['language'],$allowedLanguages)){
   include('languages/'.$_SESSION['language'].'.php');
   }
```

Then the language files would look like:

en.php:

```
$header = '<h1>My header</h1>';
```

other language, e.g. es.php:

```
$header = '<h1>Mi encabezado</h1>';
```

At the page, you then refer to the variable `$header` instead of hardcoding the text.
As the language file, where the value of the variables changes depending on the chosen language that the session variable holds, the content of your page will change accordingly.

Comment: That `include` statement is seriously messed up =) And maybe it's not the safest to put a session var directly in an include path.

Comment: Ops, you are right. I corrected that. Assuming that the server is safe and the files that exists in the folder languages, it should be safe. I will add an array of files that should be accepted, just to keep it safer.

Comment: basic concept is correct, but directly stuffing a $_GET value into $_SESSION and then using that session value in filesystem operations is somewhat of a security risk. nothing says a malicious user can't stuff in some path information and you end up loading `languages/../seekrit config dir/passwords.php`

Comment: Well, the array (`$allowedLanguages`) verifying the value of the session variable before including the file should do the trick? I'd say, if someone in fact can upload any files to any folder at the server the owner has deeper concerns than a session variable ;)

Comment: Many thanks! But how do I make the image connect with the correct language in session? Without *facepalm* please..

Comment: Well.. let's say you have a spanish flag as an image. <img alt="spanish flag" `onclick="location.href='index.php?setLanguage=es';"` src="img/spanishflag.png"/> - this will update the `session variable` to contain `es`. Of coruse you can use a regular `<a href="index.php?setLanguage=es">Español</a>` too.. or any method you find suitable :)